# Convert WKB to Esri GeodatabaseFeature

Tags: c#, sqlite, arcgis, uwp, qgis

I'm trying to make a UWP application that takes data from an SQLite database and displays it on an ArcGIS map.

I've exported a shape file from QGIS to an SQLite database. From this database I have retrieved the GEOMETRY in WKB format but am unsure how to convert it to a GeodatabaseFeature or other object that can be displayed on an ArcGIS map.

Here's my function as it stands.

```
    private void DisplayDatabase()
    {
        var tableName = (string)_DatabaseConnection.CreateCommand("SELECT f_table_name FROM geometry_columns").ExecuteDeferredQuery()[0]["f_table_name"];
        var geometryData = _DatabaseConnection.CreateCommand($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}").ExecuteDeferredQuery();

        foreach (var shape in geometryData)
        {
            //convert the data to an object
            var geometry = shape["GEOMETRY"] as byte[];

            //Need code to convert to Feature.
        }
    }
```

Comment: "convert it to a geodatabase feature" -- you mean convert and store it in a geodatabase? or are you interested in doing this on the fly (e.g. not having a GDB on disk)

Comment: On the fly. We are already using a SQLite database we don't want another one to complicate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it with WKT but I'm sure that there's a way to get from WKB to WKT.

Once in WKT you can use [this](http://puu.sh/opYnv/a63b6cece0.cs) class (sorry about the mess) to convert to JSON which can be used in the Geometry.FromJson(string) method to give you a geometry which can be assigned to a graphic and then added to a graphics layer.

Like so:

```
var graphic = new Graphic(Geometry.FromJson(ConvertWkt2Json.WKT2JSON(wktGeometry)), new SimpleMarkerSymbol() { Style = SimpleMarkerStyle.Circle, Color = Colors.Red, Size = 17 });
layer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
```